# How to fix the Hibernate "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity

I receive following error when I save the object using Hibernate

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

Comment: In want context is this error? is it with or without transient variable?

Comment: If you have relationships between the objects that you are trying to save, make sure that they are saved in the correct order. for eg: author is saved before book cause author is a must for the book. like wise.

Answer (score 1112, accepted):

You should include `cascade="all"` (if using xml) or `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` (if using annotations) on your collection mapping.

This happens because you have a collection in your entity, and that collection has one or more items which are not present in the database. By specifying the above options you tell hibernate to save them to the database when saving their parent.

Comment: Isn't this implicit?  Wouldn't you always want Hibernate to save them?

Comment: @Marcus - no, it's not. You may want to handle them manually.

Comment: Bozho is right. I've encountered circumstances where I've had collections that I wanted to manage manually because of their size, or because of business rules that don't allow all objects in a collection to get saved at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't happen only for collections but also simple one to one mappings

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to start with CascadeType.PERSIST and use persist to save?

Comment: @shevchik Using `CascadeType.PERSIST` didn't work for me. I hope someone explain the reason.

Comment: using cascade='all' will re-insert parent. How can I avoid this? without cascade, It raises the above exception

Comment: But don't just add CascadeType.ALL without using your brain. You might have successor/predecessor of the same type! This would result in some kind of infinite loop.

Comment: I wish someone replies to @Pooya comment coz i have the same problem and looking for solution.

Comment: How do you know if a collection type rather than any other type?

Comment: Cascade and transient are totally unrelated, infact the question doesn't carry any info about the context.

Comment: For anyone ever getting this error while using foreign keys: Cascade was not a solution for me as I did not want to store a collection in my parent-entity. All i wanted to do is save the id of another (foreign key) child-entity in my parent-entity. My problem seemed to be that I had used a "long" id in the child-entity, instead of a "Long" (lowercase vs uppercase). Sorry for bad use of words.

Comment: Adding 'cascade=CascadeType.ALL' fixes this error but introduces a new one when trying to save object created in different threads (using Async). Any ideas how these 2 can work together?

Comment: @Bozho Having a OneToOne relation between two entities and keeping the child_id in parent entity and using Cascade.PERSIST on that property won't save the child and I get the Error of  `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` However, using Cascade.ALL on that property fixes the problem, saves the child and its id to the parent child_id property. Why is that? isn't the Cascade.PERSIST made exactly for that reason? Why should I use ALL, I was hoping to avoid the Cascade.DELETE for safety.

Answer (score 366):

I believe this might be just repeat answer, but just to clarify, I got this on a `@OneToOne` mapping as well as a `@OneToMany`.  In both cases, it was the fact that the `Child` object I was adding to the `Parent` wasn't saved in the database yet.  So when I added the `Child` to the `Parent`, then saved the `Parent`, Hibernate would toss the `"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"` message when saving the Parent.

Adding in the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the `Parent's` reference to the `Child` solved the problem in both cases.  This saved the `Child` and the `Parent`.

Sorry for any repeat answers, just wanted to further clarify for folks.

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "performancelog_id")
public PerformanceLog getPerformanceLog() {
    return performanceLog;
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to cascade saves on a @OneToOne relationship? When creating both objects for the first time, how can I save either to the database without triggering the exception?

Comment: What if I want to save the child for some cases and not for some others?

Comment: @xtian: Well then you have to take care of the right order of saving to the database by persisting the objects with an EntityManager. In basic you just say em.persist(object1); em.persist(object2); etc.

Comment: I got this issue specifically when I used @Inheritance, in this case TABLE_PER_CLASS, I was referencing a subclass. CascadeType.ALL fixed it.

Comment: Or you have created your entity object with `new MyEntity` (without synchronizing it to the database - flushing), instead of getting its synchronized instance from database. Making Hibernate queries using that instance informs you that what you expect to be in the database differs from what you have in your app's memory. In this case - simply synchronize/get your entity instabnce from DB and use it. No CascadeType.ALL is needed then.

Comment: I am getting this issue on one of the machine but running fine on other machines. Once i save child object with childRepo.save(child) and then save parentRepo.save(parent) then it is working on all machines. Do not know the issue with only saving parent object. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 198):

### Introduction

When using JPA and Hibernate, an entity can be in one of the following 4 states:

- **New** - A newly created object that hasn’t ever been associated with a Hibernate Session (a.k.a Persistence Context) and is not mapped to any database table row is considered to be in the New or Transient state.

To become persisted we need to either explicitly call the `persist` method or make use of the transitive persistence mechanism.

- **Persistent** - A persistent entity has been associated with a database table row and it’s being managed by the currently running Persistence Context.

Any change made to such an entity is going to be detected and propagated to the database (during the Session flush-time).

- **Detached** - Once the currently running Persistence Context is closed all the previously managed entities become detached. Successive changes will no longer be tracked and no automatic database synchronization is going to happen.
- **Removed** - Although JPA demands that managed entities only are allowed to be removed, Hibernate can also delete detached entities (but only through a `remove` method call).

### Entity state transitions

To move an entity from one state to the other, you can use the `persist`, `remove` or `merge` methods.

[image: JPA entity states]

### Fixing the problem

The issue you are describing in your question:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

is caused by associating an entity in the state of  **New** to an entity that's in the state of *Managed*.

This can happen when you are associating a child entity to a one-to-many collection in the parent entity, and the collection does not `cascade` the entity state transitions.

So, you can fix this by adding cascade to the entity association that triggered this failure, as follows:

### The `@OneToOne` association

```
@OneToOne(
    mappedBy = "post",
    orphanRemoval = true,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PostDetails details;
```

> Notice the `CascadeType.ALL` value we added for the `cascade` attribute.

### The `@OneToMany` association

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post", 
    orphanRemoval = true,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Again, the `CascadeType.ALL` is suitable for the bidirectional `@OneToMany` associations.

Now, in order for the cascade to work properly in a bidirectional, you also need to make sure that the parent and child associations are in sync.

### The `@ManyToMany` association

```
@ManyToMany(
    mappedBy = "authors",
    cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, 
        CascadeType.MERGE
    }
)
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

In a `@ManyToMany` association, you cannot use `CascadeType.ALL` or `orphanRemoval` as this will propagate the delete entity state transition from one parent to another parent entity.

Therefore, for `@ManyToMany` associations, you usually cascade the `CascadeType.PERSIST` or `CascadeType.MERGE` operations. Alternatively, you can expand that to `DETACH` or `REFRESH`.

Comment: How does Hibernate determine that the instance is detached? Is it just looking at the ID and if it is null, it considers the instance detached or is there something else involved?

Comment: For merge, it runs a SELECT query. Otherwise, it checks the id and the version.

Comment: Dear Vlad, I read most of the comments below, and for me it was exactly as in the case written in the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40769546/1925356 . Do you think this is a valid solution? (For me, it seemed to work). Thanks!

Comment: Calling `merge` to `persist` an object is a bad idea. Just because it happens to work, it doesn't mean it's the right way.

Answer (score 88):

This happens when saving an object when Hibernate thinks it needs to save an object that is associated with the one you are saving.

I had this problem and did not want to save changes to the referenced object so I wanted the cascade type to be NONE.

The trick is to ensure that the ID and VERSION in the referenced object is set so that Hibernate does not think that the referenced object is a new object that needs saving. This worked for me.

Look through all of the relationships in the class you are saving to work out the associated objects (and the associated objects of the associated objects) and ensure that the ID and VERSION is set in all objects of the object tree.

Comment: This comment put me on the right track. I was assigning a new instance of the parent into a property of its child. So NH thought they were different instances.

Comment: Yes. This happens if, for example, the id of the associated object is not included (e.g. it's been ignored by @JsonIgnore). Hibernate has no way of identifying the associated entity, so it wants to save it.

Comment: Thanks! I had a foreign key referencing not the ID field on the referenced table, but a field with a UNIQUE constraint (CODE), and on creation Hibernate couldn't find the existing row from the given CODE and tried to create it on the referenced table. I solved by pre-fetching the whole entity (ID included) from its CODE, then putting into the Java entity before saving it. This time Hib didn't try to create the row and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 34):

Or, if you want to use minimal "powers" (e.g. if you don't want a cascade delete) to achieve what you want, use

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

...

@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Set<Child> children;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. CascadeType.ALL ist too broad

Comment: As of Hibernate 5.2.8, there seems to be no way to achieve the same effect with JPA annotations. For example, `@ManyToMany(cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH, DETACH})` (all but REMOVE) does not cascade updates like Hibernate's `CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE` does.

Answer (score 34):

In my case it was caused by not having `CascadeType` on the `@ManyToOne` side of the bidirectional relationship. To be more precise, I had `CascadeType.ALL` on `@OneToMany` side and did not have it on `@ManyToOne`. Adding `CascadeType.ALL` to `@ManyToOne` resolved the issue.
**One-to-many** side:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="globalConfig", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<GlobalConfigScope>gcScopeSet;
```

**Many-to-one side** (caused the problem)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="global_config_id")
private GlobalConfig globalConfig;
```

**Many-to-one** (fixed by adding `CascadeType.PERSIST`)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="global_config_id")
private GlobalConfig globalConfig;
```

Comment: If I do it this way, and save the parent entity, what's happening is there are two inserts in my parent table that is two rows. I think its because we have cascade on both parent and child entities?

Answer (score 22):

This occurred for me when persisting an entity in which the existing record in the database had a NULL value for the field annotated with @Version (for optimistic locking). Updating the NULL value to 0 in the database corrected this.

Comment: This should be a new question and it should be added as a bug, at least the misleading exception. This turned out to be the cause of my issue.

Comment: This fixes my problem

Answer (score 13):

This isn't the only reason for the error. I encountered it just now for a typo error in my coding, which I believe, set a value of an entity which was already saved.

```
X x2 = new X();
x.setXid(memberid); // Error happened here - x was a previous global entity I created earlier
Y.setX(x2);
```

I spotted the error by finding exactly which variable caused the error (in this case `String xid`). I used a `catch` around the whole block of code that saved the entity and printed the traces.

```
{
   code block that performed the operation
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); // put a break-point here and inspect the 'e'
   return ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Similar problem to mine. Afterall, when I reloaded the entity locally, set the property, then saved, it worked fine.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use `Cascade.All` until you really have to. `Role` and `Permission` have bidirectional `manyToMany` relation. Then the following code would work fine

```
    Permission p = new Permission();
    p.setName("help");
    Permission p2 = new Permission();
    p2.setName("self_info");
    p = (Permission)crudRepository.save(p); // returned p has id filled in.
    p2 = (Permission)crudRepository.save(p2); // so does p2.
    Role role = new Role();
    role.setAvailable(true);
    role.setDescription("a test role");
    role.setRole("admin");
    List<Permission> pList = new ArrayList<Permission>();
    pList.add(p);
    pList.add(p2);
    role.setPermissions(pList);
    crudRepository.save(role);
```

while if the object is just a "new" one, then it would throw the same error.

Comment: is 100% correct, the Cascade.All is the lazy solution and only should be applied when required. first, if the entity already exists, check if it is loaded in the current entity manager, if not load it.

Answer (score 9):

beside all other good answers, this could happen if you use `merge` to persist an object and accidentally forget to use merged reference of the object in the parent class. consider the following example

```
merge(A);
B.setA(A);
persist(B);
```

In this case, you merge `A` but forget to use merged object of `A`. to solve the problem you must rewrite the code like this.

```
A=merge(A);//difference is here
B.setA(A);
persist(B);
```

Answer (score 8):

It can also happen when you are having OneToMany relation and you try to add the child entity to the list in parent entity, then **retrieve** this list through parent entity (before saving this parent entity), **without saving child entity** itself, e.g.:

```
Child childEntity = new Child();
parentEntity.addChild(childEntity);
parentEntity.getChildren(); // I needed the retrieval for logging, but one may need it for other reasons.
parentRepository.save(parentEntity);
```

The error was thrown when I saved the parent entity. If I removed the retrieval in the previous row, then the error was not thrown, but of course that's not the solution.

The **solution** was saving the childEntity and **adding** that **saved child entity** to the parent entity, like this:

```
Child childEntity = new Child();
Child savedChildEntity = childRepository.save(childEntity);
parentEntity.addChild(savedChildEntity);
parentEntity.getChildren();
parentRepository.save(parentEntity);
```

Answer (score 7):

If your collection is nullable just try: `object.SetYouColection(null);`

Comment: This was totally my issue. I never would have guessed I had to manually set it to null.

Comment: This was also my issue. I wasn't using a collection, so I didn't try this at first, but I set my object to null and now it works.

Answer (score 7):

This issue happened to me when I created a new entity and an associated entity in a method marked as `@Transactional`, then performed a query before saving. Ex

```
@Transactional
public someService() {
    Entity someEntity = new Entity();
    AssocaiatedEntity associatedEntity = new AssocaitedEntity();
    someEntity.setAssociatedEntity(associatedEntity);
    associatedEntity.setEntity(someEntity);

    // Performing any query was causing hibernate to attempt to persist the new entity. It would then throw an exception
    someDao.getSomething();

    entityDao.create(someEntity);
}
```

To fix, I performed the query before creating the new entity.

Comment: Totally missed the persisted entity in the ManyToOne field was persisted through a transactional call, adding 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS) has solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

To add my 2 cents, I got this same issue when I m accidentally sending `null` as the ID. Below code depicts my scenario *(and OP didn't mention any specific scenario)*.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setDept(new Dept(deptId)); // --> when deptId PKID is null, same error will be thrown
// calls to other setters...
em.persist(emp);
```

Here I m setting the existing department id to a new employee instance without actually getting the department entity first, as I don't want to another select query to fire.

In some scenarios, `deptId` PKID is coming as `null` from calling method and I m getting the same error.

**So, watch for `null` values for PK ID**

Comment: what if its nullable?

Comment: I have similar problem. I get the exception when my deptID is 0. Any other value greater than 0 works. Funny is that I have a dept with id = 0.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Spring Data JPA then addition `@Transactional` annotation to your service implementation would solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same situation. By setting following annotation above the property made it solve the exception prompted.

The Exception I faced.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.model.Car_OneToMany
```

To overcome, the annotation I used.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @Column(name = "ListOfCarsDrivenByDriver")
    private List<Car_OneToMany> listOfCarsBeingDriven = new ArrayList<Car_OneToMany>();
```

What made Hibernate throw the exception:

This exception is thrown at your console because the child object I attach to the parent object is not present in the database at that moment.

By providing `@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})` , it tells Hibernate to save them to the database while saving the parent object.

Answer (score 4):

I just got this error because I was assigning an un-proxied entity onto another entity before saving.

I should have been linking a proxied entity instance.

See the below explanation:

```
Child saved = childRepository.save(child);

// INCORRECT
parent.setChild(child);  // <-- 'child' is NOT managed (not proxied)

// CORRECT
parent.setChild(saved);  // <-- 'saved' is managed (proxied)
```

Answer (score 3):

i get this error when i use

```
getSession().save(object)
```

but it works with no problem when I use

```
getSession().saveOrUpdate(object)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness: A

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException
```

with message

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

will also occur when you try to persist / merge an entity with a reference to another entity which happens to be **detached**.

Answer (score 2):

I think is because you have try to persist an object that have a reference to another object that is not persist yet, and so it try in the "DB side" to put a reference to a row that not exists

Answer (score 2):

In my case , issue was completely different. I have two classes let's say c1 & c2. Between C1 & C2 dependency is OneToMany. Now if i am saving C1 in DB it was throwing above error.

Resolution of this problem was to get first C2's id from consumer request and find C2 via repository call.Afterwards save c2 into C1 object .Now if i am saving C1, it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

i had this exception when i tried to add an instance to an  inexistant object , in relation @OneToOne, juste add cascading like that:

> @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

and it solve the probleme for me

Answer (score 1):

One other possible reason: in my case, I was attempting to save the child before saving the parent, on a brand new entity.

The code was something like this in a User.java model:

```
this.lastName = lastName;
this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
this.accountStatus = "Active";
this.setNewPassword(password);
this.timeJoin = new Date();
create();
```

The setNewPassword() method creates a PasswordHistory record and adds it to the history collection in User. Since the create() statement hadn't been executed yet for the parent, it was trying to save to a collection of an entity that hadn't yet been created. All I had to do to fix it was to move the setNewPassword() call after the call to create().

```
this.lastName = lastName;
this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
this.accountStatus = "Active";
this.timeJoin = new Date();
create();
this.setNewPassword(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility that can cause this error in hibernate. You may set an unsaved reference of your object `A` to an attached entity `B` and want to persist object `C`. Even in this case, you will get the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possibilities of this error some other possibilities are   also on add page or edit page. In my case I was trying to save a object AdvanceSalary. The problem is that in edit the AdvanceSalary employee.employee_id is null Because on edit I was not set the employee.employee_id. I have make a hidden field and set it. my code working absolutely fine.

```
    @Entity(name = "ic_advance_salary")
    @Table(name = "ic_advance_salary")
    public class AdvanceSalary extends BaseDO{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
        private Employee employee;

        @Column(name = "employee_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        @NotNull(message="Please enter employee Id")
        private Long employee_id;

        @Column(name = "advance_date")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
        @NotNull(message="Please enter advance date")
        private Date advance_date;

        @Column(name = "amount")
        @NotNull(message="Please enter Paid Amount")
        private Double amount;

        @Column(name = "cheque_date")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
        private Date cheque_date;

        @Column(name = "cheque_no")
        private String cheque_no;

        @Column(name = "remarks")
        private String remarks;

        public AdvanceSalary() {
        }

        public AdvanceSalary(Integer advance_salary_id) {
            this.id = advance_salary_id;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }

        public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
        }


        public Long getEmployee_id() {
            return employee_id;
        }

        public void setEmployee_id(Long employee_id) {
            this.employee_id = employee_id;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:
I was getting this exception when I was trying to create a parent and saving that parent reference to its child and then some other DELETE/UPDATE query(JPQL). So I just flush() the newly created entity after creating parent and after creating child using same parent reference. It Worked for me.

Case 2:

Parent class

```
public class Reference implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(precision=20, scale=0)
    private BigInteger id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="reference")
    private ReferenceAdditionalDetails refAddDetails;
    . 
    .
    .
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class ReferenceAdditionalDetails implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reference",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Reference reference;

    private String preferedSector1;
    private String preferedSector2;
    .
    .

}
```

In the above case where parent(Reference) and child(ReferenceAdditionalDetails) having OneToOne relationship and when you try to create Reference entity and then its child(ReferenceAdditionalDetails), it will give you the same exception. So to avoid the exception you have to set null for child class and then create the parent.(Sample Code)

```
.
.
reference.setRefAddDetails(null);
reference = referenceDao.create(reference);
entityManager.flush();
.
.
```

Comment: I was facing a problem similar to case 2, I have a C1 object reference in parent P1 object and C1 object is optional, I have to explicitly make C1 object null while saving P1 object when the user not adding C1 object.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error for all PUT HTTP transactions, after introducing optimistic locking (@Version)

At the time of updating an entity it is mandatory to send id and version of that entity. If any of the entity fields are related to other entities then for that field also we should provide id and version values, without that the JPA try to persist that related entity first as a new entity

**Example**: we have two entities --> **Vehicle**(id,Car,version) ; **Car**(id, version, brand); to update/persist Vehicle entity make sure the Car field in vehicle entity has id and version fields provided

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of solving this issue is save the both entity.
first save the child entity and then save the parent  entity.
Because parent entity is depend on child entity for the foreign key value.

Below simple exam of one to one relationship

```
insert into Department (name, numOfemp, Depno) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Employee (SSN, dep_Depno, firstName, lastName, middleName, empno) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Session session=sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(dep);
        session.save(emp);
```

Comment: It is the opposite - child entity holds the FK value and depends on parent so you need to save parent first! In the code block you have it right.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of the error is the inexistence of the setting of the value of the parent entity ; for example for a department-employees relationship you have to write this in order to fix the error :

```
Department dept = (Department)session.load(Department.class, dept_code); // dept_code is from the jsp form which you get in the controller with @RequestParam String department
employee.setDepartment(dept);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exception when I  did not persist parent object but I was saving the child. To resolve the issue, with in the same session I persisted both the child and parent objects and used  CascadeType.ALL on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to `@BeforeEach` of JUnit. And even if I saved the related entities (in my case `@ManyToOne`), I got the same error.

The problem is somehow related to the sequence that I have in my parent.
If I assign the value to that attribute, the problem is solved.

Ex.
If I have the entity Question that can have some categories (one or more) and entity Question has a sequence:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "feedbackSeq")
@Id
private Long id;
```

I have to assign the value `question.setId(1L);`

Answer (score 0):

Just make Constructor of your mapping in your base class.
Like if you want One-To-One relation in Entity A, Entity B.
if your are taking A as base class, then A must have a Constructor have B as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Cascade.ALL was adding unnecessary entry to the table, which already had same object (Generating a child value without an id does just that).
So I would have to work around with getting child object from repository first, and setting it into the main object instead of the one causing the issue.

```
Student s = studentRepo.findByName(generatedObject.getStudent().getName())
generatedObject.student(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it occurred when I tried to retrieve a related entity using reference to an entity with null id.

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
@Id
private Long id;
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
@OneToOne
private User user;
}

interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
Address findByUser(User user);
}

User user = new User(); // this is transient, does not have id populated
// user.setId(1L) // works fine if this is uncommented

addressRepository.findByUser(user); // throws exception
```

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this problem from time to time in unit tests, I can suggest a solution. You can add the `DirtiesContext` annotation above the test class definition, you probably won't get this error.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
```

For more detailed usage, you can see the details in this link.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html