# Hibernate Self reference Parent-Child

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I know there are loads of entries about this topic. I have already read all of them searching for the problem I am facing.

I have a class/table with a self-reference. This is the Class

```
public class Comment {

    private Integer id;
    private Comment parent;
    private Issue   issue;
    private User    author;
    private String  body;
    private Date    created;
    private Date    updated;

    private Set<Comment> childs;

    // All setters and getters
}
```

And here you can see the hbm.xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Comment" table="COMMENTS">

  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="ID"/>
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <many-to-one cascade="all"
   class="Comment" fetch="join" name="parent">
   <column name="PARENT" not-null="false"/>
  </many-to-one>

  <many-to-one class="Issue"
   fetch="join" name="issue">
   <column name="ISSUE" not-null="true"/>
  </many-to-one>

  <many-to-one class="User"
   fetch="join" name="author">
   <column name="AUTHOR" not-null="true"/>
  </many-to-one>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="body" type="java.lang.String">
   <column name="BODY" not-null="true"/>
  </property>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="created" type="java.util.Date">
   <column name="CREATED"/>
  </property>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="updated" type="java.util.Date">
   <column name="UPDATED"/>

  </property>
  <set cascade="delete" fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true"
   name="childs" sort="unsorted" table="COMMENTS">
   <key>
    <column name="ID" not-null="true"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Comment"/>
  </set>

 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

So far everything is fine. But I must have an error somewhere because, when I am running this unit test

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

User user = new User("loginName", "password", "firstName", "lastName", "eMail");
session.save(user);
session.flush();
session.clear();

Issue issue = new Issue();
session.save(issue);
session.flush();
session.clear();

Comment parent = new Comment(issue, user, "body_parent");
session.save(parent);

Comment child = new Comment(issue, user, "body_child_1");
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChilds().add(child);
session.save(child);
session.flush();
session.clear();

parent = (Comment) session.createQuery("from Comment comment where comment.body='body_parent'").uniqueResult();

System.out.println(parent);
System.out.println(parent.getChilds().iterator().next());
```

I added the last two lines in order to show you the problem I am facing right now:

```
COMMENT = [id=1, parentId=<root>, issueId=1, authorId=1, body=body_parent, created=2014-03-08 19:28:54.832, updated=2014-03-08 19:28:54.832, numChilds=1]
COMMENT = [id=1, parentId=<root>, issueId=1, authorId=1, body=body_parent, created=2014-03-08 19:28:54.832, updated=2014-03-08 19:28:54.832, numChilds=1]
```

Both parent and child are the same! I don't really understand the problem here. **When I retrieve the child through a query the result is correct but when I get the child through getChild() there's not query to retrieve the its childs.**

Have you any idea? Any clue? I do not see the light at the end of the tunnel here :-/

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: this does not answers your question, but `xml` is evil, use `annotations`

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Could you elaborate on how XML is evil?

Comment: Your relation is backwards by the way. It should be one-to-many instead of many-to-one.

Comment: @Bart It's difficult to read/write/understand and least but not last - when you look at your entity it tells you nothing about the persistence layer and you have to look-up everything you want to know from that ugly, unreadable pile of **** called xml. If you are using Java 1.5+ I cannot find any reason to prefer xml over annotations. That's it - nothing more and nothing less :)

Comment: The purpose of this project is merely for learning. I started doing everything with hbm.xml and I don't really think in changing to Annotations...

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Good points. I guess evil is not the right word. XML is not recommended since annotations are more declarative. On the other side XML does not clutter your code with annotations. So I guess both have benefits but for general use annotations are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have realized what the problem was! Well, there was couple of problems.

First, there was no `parent_id` field in neither the DB nor the class. 
Second, there was no exception because I activated `inverse` property to the set.

The combination of both issues was the problem.

Below, I post the working solution.

**Comment.java**

```
public class Comment {
    private Integer      id;
    private Integer      parentId; // Parent ID was missing
    private Issue        issue;
    private User         author;
    private String       body;
    private Date         created;
    private Date         updated;

    private Comment      parent; // Reference to parent though parentId
    private Set<Comment> childs = new HashSet<Comment>(0);


    protected Comment () {

    }

   // All setters and getters
}
```

**Comment.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.Comment" table="COMMENTS">

  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="ID"/>
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="parentId" type="java.lang.Integer" update="false" insert="false" column="PARENT_ID" />

  <many-to-one class="es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.Issue"
   fetch="join" name="issue">
   <column name="ISSUE"/>
  </many-to-one>

  <many-to-one class="es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.User"
   fetch="join" name="author">
   <column name="AUTHOR"/>
  </many-to-one>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="body" type="java.lang.String">
   <column name="BODY"/>
  </property>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="created" type="java.util.Date">
   <column name="CREATED"/>
  </property>

  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="updated" type="java.util.Date">
   <column name="UPDATED"/>
  </property>

  <many-to-one name="parent" class="es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.Comment" column="PARENT_ID" not-null="false" />

  <set name="childs" table="COMMENTS"  lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false">
   <key column="PARENT_ID" />
   <one-to-many class="es.kazbeel.geckobugtracker.model.Comment"/>
  </set>

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I hope this is helpful for someone in the future. This is the first time I post a self-solution :)

Answer (score 2):

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149536/org-hibernate-transientobjectexception-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-i)

> your issue will be resolved by properly defining cascading depedencies
>   or by saving the referenced entities before saving the entity that
>   references. Defining cascading is really tricky to get right because
>   of all the subtle variations in how they are used.

cascade="delete"

check the options all|none|save-update|delete|all-delete-orphan

`session.save(child);` instead of this try `cascade="all" and session.save(parent)` so that all child objects will be saved with parent.

Comment: I tried everything related to "cascade" but with no results. I believe the problem resides somewhere else. As I highlighted, both parent and child are persisted in the DB, the problem is that I am not able to retrieve the child of the parent through `getChilds()`. In fact, calling the function does not fire any new query on the DB, that's actually the principal problem. I'm sure this is a silly problem, I don't see where though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a shot using the code below:

```
Comment parent = new Comment(issue, user, "body_parent");
Comment child = new Comment(issue, user, "body_child_1");
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChilds().add(child);
session.save(parent);
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

Comment: I get this exception `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` as the child is not saved...

Comment: <set cascade="all" fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true"
   name="childs" sort="unsorted" table="COMMENTS">   

try a cascade insert