# struts 1 throws org.hibernate.TransientObjectException

Tags: hibernate, struts-1

I am trying to add activity auditing to my struts 1 application. I change an object and then I want to create a row in my auditing table that refers to the changed object. I am getting TransientObjectException because I've changed the referent object. I tried flushing the session, but that didn't solve it and I'm not sure why.

```
merchant.setTrusted(false);
merchantDAO.saveOrUpdate(merchant);
// trying to resolve org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.rc.model.ActivityAudit.user
SessionManagerFactory.getSessionManager(DatasourceType.M).getSession().flush();

ActivityAuditManager.addActivityAudit("Set merchant to untrusted", merchant, userAccount);
```

where ActivityAuditManager.addActivityAudit() is:

```
public static void addActivityAudit(String action, Merchant merchant, IMerchantUserAccount user) {
    ActivityAudit activityAudit = new ActivityAudit(merchant, action, user, new Date());
    activityAuditDAO.saveOrUpdate(activityAudit);
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

but as far as I can tell I *am*.

ETA mapping:

```
<class name="com.rc.model.ActivityAudit" table="activity_audit" discriminator-value="0">
...
    <many-to-one name="merchant" class="com.rc.model.Merchant"
                 column="merchantid" unique="false" not-null="true" cascade="none"/>
...
```

I tried `cascade="all"` and `cascade="save-update"` and neither improves the situation.

ETA: See my own answer, below, but `cascade="save-update"` actually did fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems. The second one, which was uncovered when I fixed the first, initially obscured the fact that `cascade="save-update"` actually did resolve this issue.

In this question,
[object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)
user [nanospeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951984/nanospeck) posted a method for debugging that helped me a lot.

I didn't notice the second problem until I used that debugging method and examined the Exception in more detail.