# Is there any easy way to persist one object that contains many references to other entities objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project, I use hibernate and there is an object that has at least 30 references to other objects which are entities as well.

Of course it's not possible to just call

```
session.save(myHeavyObj);
```

Because it will throw "object references an unsaved transient instance".

I want to persist all objects. Is there any easy way to persist one object that contains many references to other entities objects?

UPDATE

```
@Entity
class MyClass{
     //basic elements
     @ElementCollection
     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) //some don't have this line
     @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     List<Medication> allMeds = new ArrayList<Medication>(); //Medication is Entity

    //and more lists like this. 
}
```

SOLUTION

It worked by adding

```
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Do you want to persist the other entities as well or not? Sorry, not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes. I want to persist them all. And according to my very limited knowledge, I have to persist them one by one which is not feasible since I have around 30 references inside the object.
Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Could you post a sample of you root entity? Gavin has a suggestion on the Cascade type below but I'm not sure that this is all of your problem.

Comment: I added code sample as suggested.

Comment: Someone else asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `CascadeType` property to `PERSIST` or `ALL` on your relationship annotations. This will tell hibernate what actions to "cascade" to the other entities. This will look like

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private MyOtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

Comment: So when I persist MyEntity, I don't need to persist the other one (MyOtherEntity)?

Comment: just call save on the MyEntity and it will call save on the other entity for you. Same goes for delete if you change it to `All`. Give it a try!