# org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jax-rs

i have two entities and a oneToOne Relation between those entities.
The first one:

```
    @Entity
    public class B{
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = A.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", referencedColumnName = "aId", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private A a;

    .....
}
```

The another one:

```
   @Entity
    public class A{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;  
}
```

i try to read a json'file with JAX-RS and get the exception:

```
{
    "a": {
        "name": "my name"
        "b": {
            "attribut": "my attribut...."
        }
}
```

i my controller

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/send")
    public Response post(MyRoot myRoot) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(D.class);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory acbFactory = applicationContext
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        acbFactory.autowireBean(this);

        a = myRoot.getA();
        em.persist(a);
        b = a.getB();
        em.persist(b);
        return Response.status(200).entity(myRoot).build();
    }
```

MyRoot return an A-Entity.
i get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : B.a -> A
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.noCascade(CascadingActions.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 52 more
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)

Comment: why do you mean with "save the transient instance before flushing"? can you explain please?