# "Save transient object before flushing" error

Tags: java, spring, object, transient

I tried to save one of my entity Site containing a User, this User is registered in database and I don't want  to save it too. 
 The problem is when I try to save the site, I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.project.netmg.bo.impl.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.project.netmg.bo.impl.User
```

I think, it try to save the user too but it's not that I want. I just want to search the good user and assign it to the site.

java code :

```
public String saveSite(@Valid @ModelAttribute SiteForm siteForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel) {

    populateSiteforSave(siteForm);
    _siteService.saveSite(siteForm.getSite());
    return WebConstants.REDIRECT_TO_VIEW_SITE_URL + siteForm.getSite().getSiteName();
}

private void populateSiteforSave(SiteForm siteForm) {
    siteForm.getSite().setCountry((Country) _countryService.getCountryByName(siteForm.getSite().getCountry().getName()));
    siteForm.getSite().setBusiness((Business) _businessService.getBusinessById(siteForm.getSite().getBusiness().getId()));
    siteForm.getSite().setStatus((Status) _statusService.getStatusById(siteForm.getSite().getStatus().getId()));
    if (!siteForm.getLocalItFullName().isEmpty()) {
        siteForm.getSite().setLocalIt(_userService.findUserByUserFullName(siteForm.getLocalItFullName())); // user
    } else {
        siteForm.getSite().setLocalIt(null);
    }
    if (!siteForm.getRifFullName().isEmpty()) {
        siteForm.getSite().setRif(_userService.findUserByUserFullName(siteForm.getRifFullName())); //user
    } else {
        siteForm.getSite().setRif(null);
    }
    if (siteForm.getSite().getLocalContact().getId() != null) {
        siteForm.getSite().setLocalContact((User) _userService.findUserByUsername(siteForm.getSite().getLocalContact().getUsername())); //user
    }
}
```

Site class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SITE", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "SITE_COUNTRY_ID", "SITE_NAME" }) })
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, withModifiedFlag = true)
public class Site implements ISite {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -390717603276436784L;

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SITE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

/** The site address. */
@Column(name = "SITE_ADDRESS", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_ADDRESS)
private String address;

/** The site analog phone number. */
@Column(name = "SITE_ANALOG_PHONE_NUMBER", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_ANALOG_PHONE_NUMBER)
private String analogPhoneNumber;

/** The site comment. */
@Column(name = "SITE_COMMENT", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_COMMENT)
private String comment;

/** The site entity code. */
@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 3 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_ENTITY_CODE", nullable = false)
private long entityCode;

/** The site invoice code. */
@Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 10 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_INVOICE_CODE", nullable = false)
private long invoiceCode;

/** The site local it phone. */
@Column(name = "SITE_LOCAL_IT_PHONE", length = BusinessConstants.SITE_LOCAL_IT_PHONE)
private String localItPhone;

/** The site name. */
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "SITE_NAME", nullable = false, length = BusinessConstants.SITE_NAME)
private String siteName;

/** The site subnet. */
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "SITE_SUBNET", nullable = false, length = BusinessConstants.SITE_SUBNET)
private String subnet;

/** The site user number. */
@Digits(integer = 4, fraction = 0, message = "Please enter max 4 digits")
@Column(name = "SITE_USER_NUMBER")
private Long userNumber;

/** The business. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_BUSINESS_ID", nullable = false)
private Business business;

/** The country. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_COUNTRY_ID")
private Country country;

/** The local contact. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_LOCAL_CONTACT", nullable = true)
private User localContact;

/** The local it. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_LOCAL_IT", nullable = true)
private User localIt;

/** The rif. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_RIF", nullable = true)
private User rif;

/** The status. */
@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SITE_STATUS_ID", nullable = false)
private Status status;

/** The end date. */
@Column(name = "SITE_END_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
private Date endDate = null;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "userSites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotAudited
private Set<IUser> siteUsers;
```

User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements IUser {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6741623705511494367L;
private static final String USER_ID = "USER_ID";

/** The user id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = USER_ID)
private Long id;

/** The user first name. */
@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", length = BusinessConstants.USER_FIRSTNAME, nullable = false)
@NotNull
private String userFirstName;

/** The user last name. */
@Column(name = "LASTNAME", length = BusinessConstants.USER_LASTNAME, nullable = false)
@NotNull
private String userLastName;

/** The user email. */
@Column(name = "EMAIL", length = BusinessConstants.USER_EMAIL)
@NotNull
private String userEmail;

/** The user uid. */
@Column(name = "LOGIN", length = BusinessConstants.USER_LOGIN, nullable = false, unique = true)
@NotNull
private String username;

@Valid
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROF_ID", nullable = false)
private Profile profile;

@BatchSize(size = 20)
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Site.class)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_SITE",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SITE_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<ISite> userSites;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Region.class)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_REGION",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "REGION_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<IRegion> userRegions;

@BatchSize(size = 20)
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Zone.class )
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ZONE",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ZONE_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<IZone> userZones;

@BatchSize(size = 20)
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Country.class )
@JoinTable(name = "USER_COUNTRY",
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = USER_ID, nullable = false) },
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = false) })
private Set<ICountry> userCountries;

@Transient
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

@Transient
private String userFullName;
```

Comment: @SteveChaloner I tried it but this is for save the child object but I don't want to save the children, I just want to associate it. and when  I make cascade.all I get an error saying that my object User contain some missing fields

Comment: See this answer to the above post http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286061/1063929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have it both ways. If the object graph includes the `User`, then it will (have to) be persisted if changed in your code. Have you considered what it evens means to fetch a `Site` (including a `User`), then change the `localContact` and persist the `Site` again?

If you want the `localContact` to be settable in the object graph, but not persisted, then it can be annotated with [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html):

```
/** The local contact. */
@Transient
private User localContact;
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: thank you for help, it's working but I don't really understand why the localContact caused the error. Can you explain what you mean please ?

Comment: Most likely the `User` you set on `localContact` does not have an ID corresponding to an existing user in the DB, and since you haven't explicitly set the cascading option mentioned in another answer, you will have to explicitly persist the `User` first.

Comment: ok understand thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you annotate cascade=CascadeType.ALL to your entity object mapping

eg :

```
     @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private String entityType;
```

Comment: Yes but this is for save the children entity no ? I don't want to save it into database, I just want to assign it. and when I make cascade.all I get an error on my field annotate @NotNull

Comment: One more important detail, the problem is just when asseting a user null. do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you show how your entity class look like.

Comment: Post edited with the classes site and user