# Why are Entities not persisted in a JPA/Hibernate setup with Spring 3.2?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

When I try to persist an object nothing happens (Exception, error, etc) and I didn't find the cause.

My suspect is that the problem is the transactional control of Spring, because the queries work fine.

I'm using Spring 3.2 with JPA 2 and the JPA implementation is the Hibernate 4.2.18.

---

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOLAR")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Dolar.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT d FROM Dolar d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Dolar.FIND_BY_EMPRESA, query = "SELECT d FROM Dolar d WHERE d.empresa = :e")    
})

public class Dolar implements Serializable, AbstractEntity {

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Transient
public static final String FIND_BY_EMPRESA = "Dolar.findByEmpr";
@Transient
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Dolar.findAll";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPRESA_ID")
private Empresa empresa;

@Column(name = "VALOR")
private BigDecimal valor;

public Dolar() {
}
```

**Managed bean**

```
@Controller("dolarMB")
@Scope(ViewScope.VIEW_SCOPE)
public class DolarMB extends AbstractMB<Dolar> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7711019409135908863L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DolarMB.class);

    @Autowired
    private DaoDolar dao;

    private List<Dolar> lista;
    private Dolar cadastro;
    private Empresa empresa;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
    cadastro =  new Dolar();
    LOGGER.info("init:\n" + cadastro);
    }


    public void salvar() {

    if (!validate()){
       LOGGER.info("erro no cadastro");
    }else{

        cadastro = dao.salvar(cadastro);
          limparFiltro();

        }

    }
}
```

**Dao**

```
@Repository
public class DolarDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Dolar> implements DolarDao{

@Override
public Dolar recuperarPorEmpresa(Empresa e) {
    Query q = getConexao().createNamedQuery(Dolar.FIND_BY_EMPRESA);
    q.setParameter("empr", e);
    return (Dolar) q.getSingleResult();
}
} 


@Repository
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T extends AbstractEntity> implements GenericDao<T> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private Class<T> clazz;
private Method m;

public GenericDaoImpl() {
   carregarClass(); 
   carregarMetodoId();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public final T salvar(T e) {
    if (e == null)
        return null;
    try {

        if (m.invoke(e) != null) {
            e = em.merge(e);
        } else {
            em.persist(e);
        }
        return e;

     } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
         Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(e1);
     } catch (Exception e2) {
         Logger.getLogger(getClass()).error(e2);
     }

return null;
}
```

**After the em.persist(e), the log show me this**

```
08-04-2015 18:04:15 DEBUG (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:136) - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@46e82828] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7113aac4] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@46e82828] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7113aac4] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (AbstractSaveEventListener.java:499) - Transient instance of: br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar
 - Transient instance of: br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (DefaultPersistEventListener.java:202) - Saving transient instance
 - Saving transient instance
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (AbstractSaveEventListener.java:167) - Saving [br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<null>]
 - Saving [br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<null>]
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (ActionQueue.java:192) - Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar] object
 - Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar] object
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (ActionQueue.java:208) - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<delayed:2>]]
 - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<delayed:2>]]
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (ActionQueue.java:232) - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
 - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:214) - No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<delayed:2>]]
 - No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar#<delayed:2>]]
08-04-2015 18:04:15 TRACE (UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:121) - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
 - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
08-04-2015 18:06:30 DEBUG (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:136) - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@46e82828] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7113aac4] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@46e82828] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@7113aac4] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
08-04-2015 18:06:30 TRACE (AbstractSaveEventListener.java:482) - Persistent instance of: br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar
 - Persistent instance of: br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar
08-04-2015 18:06:30 TRACE (DefaultPersistEventListener.java:174) - Ignoring persistent instance
 - Ignoring persistent instance
08-04-2015 18:06:30 TRACE (UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:121) - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
 - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
```

**This is my configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- Datasource  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}"/>
        <!-- C3P0 properties -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="4" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="120" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SALES-HOMOLOG" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>br.com.mycompany.sales.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${database.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.showSql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${database.formatSql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>     





</beans>
```

**my persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SALES-HOMOLOG" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar</class>
    <class>br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Empresa</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: there is some error in your log?

Comment: there certainly will be information in the log, that will suggest to you where the problem is

Comment: How do you tell hibernate what are your entity classes?

Comment: Besides possible errors, you can and should do a lot more debugging yourself. "Nothing happens" is way to vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem updating a dependency of Spring.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I updated to version 2.0.8 and the transaction control worked.

Answer (score 0):

The packages to scan entities shows something else than your logs shows as 
entity class. 
Your class is `br.com.mycompany.sales.model.Dolar` and the package that should hold the entity classes is defined like this `br.com.mycompany.sales.dao`. Either move the class to that package or change the package name on the class.

Comment: The ' packages to scan ' has been updated in question. I tell what entities are mapped through the persistence.xml file

Comment: I still see the `br.com.mycompany.sales.dao` in the question. Is the same on your code?

Comment: Now, I updated the packageToScan value for the same of Dolar class, but still has an error

Comment: Maybe this is your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be

Answer (score 0):

first off you should show us the code that where you are trying to save the instance. try calling the method below and I think it will work.

```
    @Override
@Transactional
public final T salvar(T e)
```

this if from your GenericDaoImpl try using this.

Comment: Tks, @giannisapi. I forgot but now I added my controller to the question. I already use the method salvar(T e). It's called from DolarMB controller.

Comment: if i see correctly your default constructor for dolar does not create anything, before this:  cadastro = dao.salvar(cadastro); try assign values to the properties of your object, give it value for empresa and valor.

Comment: The values of object are assign by web page but I made a test putting values and nothing changed. Like this: `cadastro.setEmpresa(255L);
     cadastro.setId(20L);
     cadastro = dao.salvar(cadastro);` I changed the type of property empresa to Long too.

Comment: honestly this is a very strange bug, and i am sure the bug is something that we just can not see. if you want send me the code and I will try to fix, it must be something stupid

Comment: try adding this em.getTransaction().commit(); and tell us if an exception occurs

Comment: I followed your tip and the exception is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`

Comment: maybe if you try em.commit() is it available?