# Hibernate: Save the transient Instance before fliushing?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, persistence, transient

I am getting the following error with my Java code when attempting to delete rows from the database:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.my.package.dog.kennel -> com.my.package.kennel
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be) question which helped me understand the error. However, I am not sure **which** `entity` the error is suggesting I need to save before flushing?

is it the `kennel` or `dog` entity?

Comment: show us the lines of code that does the db operation

Comment: Can you not tell via the error message which one should need to be saved?