# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

I have:

Document ManyToOne Template

When I click save Template see error, I try add `@JsonIgnore` then OK but this entity not show in UI

**Document.Java**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
//cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST or cascade = CascadeType.ALL not success
@JoinColumn(name = "template_id")
private Template template;
```

**Error**

```
{"timestamp":"2017-03-29T04:03:30.553+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException","message":"org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Document.template -> com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Template; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Document.template -> com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Template","path":"/api/documents"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be)

Comment: I try cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} or cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST not success, if add them then template save OK but in document not save

Comment: {"timestamp":"2017-03-29T04:21:46.898+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException","message":"detached entity passed to persist: com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Template; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.paragonsystem.capture.domain.Template","path":"/api/documents"}

Comment: ok then make sure before saving both object not null .

Comment: Yes, I think issue in private Template template;

Comment: I have  came across this issue many times

Comment: You can help me fix this issue, I search and fix 2 days but not resolved

Comment: I happy to do that .As i told you that this error happens whenever you try to save the Object without saving the appropriate Joins. So make sure before persist all the join object you are setting.I mean both way you need to set.

Comment: I think if you have TeamViewer you can explain persist for me understand, I feel I can't fix this bug because I spend much time on this issue but can't don't understand them

Comment: Template not posted in the question. Persistence code not posted in the question. JSON is utterly irrelevant to the problem. Debug it using the LOG!

Comment: '@JsonIgnore' flags a field not be serialized into a JSON to avoid cyclic references. It could indicate another problem, post contents of 'Document' and 'Template' classes if is this question still open, otherwise, close it.