# Hibernate @ManyToOne do not update table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entities - User and Role with mapping `@ManyToOne`. I want to change role in user, but Role want's to be updated too.

User entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private Role role;
```

role entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
private Set<User> users;
```

The error I get is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: com.spring.model.Role
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:144)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)

My tables in DB are not set with CASCADE UPDATE or INSERT. I wasn't able to find appropriate solution. Thanks for your help

EDIT:

This is how I update User

```
public void update(User user) {
        User entity = dao.findById(user.getId());
        if(entity!=null) {
            entity.setRole(user.getRole());
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:

My hibernate configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.spring.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.spring.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of the code you are using to change the role in a user?

Comment: I think it would helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, I found that post but it didn't help me

Comment: Can you show the code how the User object is populated for `update(User user)`? And your entities with your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `cascade` attribute of the `OneToMany` annotation, it does not have any relationship with the database `cascade` operations (but can be affected by that).

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="role", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<User> users;
```

This way the operation will be propagated to the collection elements. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be) for more info.

You can also modify the cascade property of the `ManyToOne` annotation.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

Comment: No, it is still the same.

Comment: shouldn't you remove `updatable = false` from the `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: I copy them by accident, yes they should be removed

Comment: Should I try to change tables in DB with no update and no insert? I am adding my hibernate java configuration

Comment: Even if I remove updatable = false, error still persist

Comment: Try removing `insertable=false`.

Comment: Do you have exactly this? `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;`

Comment: if I have exactly @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")  and @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="role", orphanRemoval = true) then Role is being updated too

Comment: OK, I find out I can't update table ROLE with NO UPDATE, because I am updating not primary key from USER . When I update entities with cascade types and orphanremoval, my table ROLE is updated with new rows and USER is updated with new key from table ROLE. I am being quite desperate here ...

Comment: Where did you had specified `NO UPDATE`?

Comment: Nowhere, I wanted to update my tables in DB with ON DELETE NO ACTION. But it is not possible with design of my tables I have. I am not going to use annotations for entities and update each separately. thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome, anyway the normal case it to use `NO ACTION` in the database since hibernate handles that for you.