# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing using hibernate spatial

Tags: java, hibernate, jts

I am triying to execute this query:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("select p from PointsEntity p " + "where within(p.coordinates,:polygon) = true");
```

But I have this exception:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.gisapp.springboot.backend.apirest.models.entity.PolygonEntity

This is the PolygonEntity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "user_email")
private String userEmail;

@Column(name = "point_name")
private String pointName;

@Column(name = "coordinates")
private Polygon coordinates;
```

I have read a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-be) but watching the entity, the solution has been already implemented in the UserEntity which contains the polygon´s collection:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<PointsEntity> pointsList;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<PolygonEntity> polygonsList;
```

Why do I have this exception?

Comment: The error probably has nothing to do with the query you are showing. What other changes are made within the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have used another way to use the within method.

I have created a temporal table and an entity to save the polygon, later I execute this query:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("select p from PointsEntity p, TempPolygonEntity t "
        + "where within(p.coordinates, t.coordinates) = true");
```

The polygon is saved and later is deleted after the use.