# Saving an entity when its child entity is initialized by one of its unique fields throws org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider the two classes below:

```
class TerminalMaintenance{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_MAINTENANCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name ="SEQ_MAINTENANCE", sequenceName = "SEQ_MAINTENANCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="code", unique = true)
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Terminal terminal;

    public TerminalMaintenance() {
    }

    public TerminalMaintenance(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public TerminalMaintenance(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
...
}

class Terminal{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_TERMINAL")
    @SequenceGenerator(name ="SEQ_TERMINAL", sequenceName = "SEQ_TERMINAL", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="code", unique = true)
    private String code;
    
    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "terminal")
    private List<TerminalMaintenance> maintenances;
...

}

interface TerminalRepo extends JpaRepository<Terminal, Long>{
    
}

interface TerminalMaintenanceRepo extends JpaRepository<TerminalMaintenance, Long>{

}
```

When I want to save the TerminalMaintenance entity, I already know `id` of its `Terminal` entity and I do not load its entire terminal object in order to persist object `TerminalMaintenance` like:

```
TerminalMaintenance terminalMaintenance = new TerminalMaintenance();
Terminal terminal = new Terminal(1); \\ using id constructor

terminalMaintenance.setTerminal(terminal);


terminalMaintenanceRepo.save(terminalMaintenance);
```

And it works fine. But when I want to instantiate the object `Terminal` using its `code` field - which is unique - like :

```
TerminalMaintenance terminalMaintenance = new TerminalMaintenance();
Terminal terminal = new Terminal("core123"); \\ using code constructor

terminalMaintenance.setTerminal(terminal);


terminalMaintenanceRepo.save(terminalMaintenance);
```

it thorws :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.noorbank.entity.tms.TerminalMaintenance.terminal -> ir.noorbank.entity.tms.Terminal; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.noorbank.entity.tms.TerminalMaintenance.terminal -> ir.noorbank.entity.tms.Terminal

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at ir.noorbank.repo.TerminalMaintenanceRepositoryTest.test(TerminalMaintenanceRepositoryTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.noorbank.entity.tms.TerminalMaintenance.terminal -> ir.noorbank.entity.tms.Terminal
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.noorbank.entity.tms.TerminalMaintenance.terminal -> ir.noorbank.entity.tms.Terminal
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.noCascade(CascadingActions.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1408)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    ... 88 more
```

I also tried `@NaturalId` above `code` property of `Terminal` but there is no change.

So, Is there a way to persist an entity by initializing its sub-entity using one of its unique properties instead of initializing it by `id` property?

p.s: Terminal with `id == 1 and code == code123` is already persisted in the database.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/how-to-fix-the-hibernate-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save

Comment: @Chinez Unfortunately not. Did you read my question? It works when I initialize the child entity using its id but not when initialized with code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
TerminalMaintenance terminalMaintenance = new TerminalMaintenance();
Terminal terminal = new Terminal(1); \\ using id constructor

terminalMaintenance.setTerminal(terminal);


terminalMaintenanceRepo.save(terminalMaintenance);
```

works in Hibernate because the `Terminal` object contains the identifier and, unlike JPA, Hibernate can work just fine if the parent entity is represented by a POJO that has the `id` set.

On the other hand, this code:

```
TerminalMaintenance terminalMaintenance = new TerminalMaintenance();
Terminal terminal = new Terminal("core123"); \\ using code constructor

terminalMaintenance.setTerminal(terminal);


terminalMaintenanceRepo.save(terminalMaintenance);
```

doesn't work because the `Terminal` object reference doesn't have the `id` set, so there's no way for Hibernate to know what value to set for the associated FK column.

Comment: Now I understand and thanks a bunch. But one more little thing, I am not using hibernate I am using spring data jpa -which I think uses JPA under the hood!. So, can we conclude jpa also behaves the same way?

Comment: By default, Spring Data JPA uses Hibernate. Check out the stacktrace you added in the question and you'll see the Hibernate classes that throw the exception.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Great answer! Out of curiosity, using `new Terminal(1)` in this case has `em.getReference()/session.load()` semantics (assuming no `CascadeType.MERGE`), right? I tried looking it up in the docs, but without success

Comment: The dummy POJO is a Hibernate feature only. The [`getReference`](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/) or the Spring Repository `getOne` methods are JPA compliant and allow you to initialize the Proxy object later.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. TBH I'm genuinely surprised that the attempt with `new Terminal(1)` works.

You need to fetch the existing entity (`terminalRepository.findByCode("123")`) and use the result. Otherwise, as far as JPA is concerned, `new Terminal("core123")` is a brand new entity.

Comment: yeah! and I am trying to figure it out how  `new Terminal(1)` works. Since it really works, there should be a way `new Terminal("core123")` work too