# Save Entity througth CascadeType

Tags: spring, jpa

i try too save Provider, which have a  Set  of Address, but it return Server Error.

i try too save Provider, which have a  Set  of Address, but it return Server Error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3jb6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idQ1a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwoIo.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the server error looks like this:
`object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

You should have something like this in the Address class:

```
@OneToMany(
mappedBy = "provider", 
orphanRemoval = true,
cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302814/5902295

If it's not that error, you could edit your post and add a screenshot.

Comment: is not the Error error look like  Unable to find com.example.eshop_backend.model.Address with id ab31fecf-40a6-4052-8995-91a614320e18

Answer (score 0):

I think while saving provider you are not getting address that's why it's showing EntityNotFoundException.

You can try with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in your address mapping so it will fetch addresses immediately.